# FullCalendar Won't Show

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, laravel-8

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    
    var booking = @json($events);
    
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
        },
    });
});
```

Whenever I implement the code above, the full calendar doesn't show but when I comment out `var booking = @json($events);`, the full calendar appears.

I tried the code below and it still didn't work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var events = JSON.parse('@json($events)');

    console.log(events)

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next,today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        }
    })
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting on the browser console? are you sure you are getting something on that javascript when you use one or the other? do you get data as expected? Is this being run inside a blade? You need to add more info

Comment: console log `@json($events)` and see the output

Comment: Output for the console.log: calendar.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at calendar.js:2:18)

Comment: An update. When i embed the script on the blade template (laravel) everything works but when i try to reference the script it stops stops showing